java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null in flutter
`please am having issues connecting my project to firebase.
i have initialized firbase in the main.dart and added the latest dependences for firebase yet still getting error.


ERROR Message i got when i ran the app
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61148/B_vHAEnC2Q0=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
E/flutter ( 8614): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null., ExecutionException, Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null., Stacktrace: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "apiKey" is null.
E/flutter ( 8614):  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
`Future main () async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  
       await Firebase.initializeApp(
      // name: 'myApp',

           

options: const FirebaseOptions(
apiKey: "AIzaSyADtdL5o92bi0vA0gjVk7n0T-yWIv6tYAc",
appId: "1:789598705260:android:68eae709b4390260d62a49",
messagingSenderId: "789598705260",
` projectId: "myApp-d4b86",
       ) `


 

I was expecting the app to initialized and connect to firebase, but got an error`

